# Wrong row selected for edit after applying filter in prime faces 5.2

Tags: primefaces

i have problem in row selection after applying default filter using primefaces 5.2 and jsf 2.2
Primefaces default filter work fine but when i select row to edit i got a wrong row .
 My code is attached below :

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    template="../template/template.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="container clearfix">
        <ui:insert>

            <h:form id="Type_Utilisateur_Form">

                <p:commandLink action="#{typeUtilisateurBean.create()}"
                    oncomplete="PF('popAddTypeUtilisateur').show();"
                    style="font-size: 15px;">
                        Add user type                       
                    </p:commandLink>


                <p:outputPanel id="Type_Utilisateur_List">
                    <p:dataTable var="typeUtilisateur"
                        value="#{typeUtilisateurBean.listTypeUtilisateur}"
                        widgetVar="Type_Utilisateur_Table" rows="3" paginator="true"
                        rendered="true" emptyMessage="No records found with given criteria"
                        >

                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <p:outputPanel >
                                <p:inputText id="globalFilter"
                                    onkeyup="PF('Type_Utilisateur_Table').filter()"
                                    style="width:150px" placeholder="Search fields" />
                            </p:outputPanel>
                        </f:facet>

                        <p:column headerText="User Type designation"
                            sortBy="#{typeUtilisateur.designationTypeUtilisateur}"
                            filterBy="#{typeUtilisateur.designationTypeUtilisateur}"
                            filterStyle="display:none">
                            <h:outputText
                                value="#{typeUtilisateur.designationTypeUtilisateur}" />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="Actions" style="width:120px">
                            <p:outputPanel>

                                <p:commandLink action="#{typeUtilisateurBean.getRow()}"
                                    oncomplete="PF('popEditTypeUtilisateur').show();">
                                    <p:graphicImage value="../template/images/file_edit.png"
                                        width="48" height="48"></p:graphicImage>
                                </p:commandLink>

                                <p:commandLink action="#{typeUtilisateurBean.delete}"
                                    update=":Type_Utilisateur_Form:Type_Utilisateur_List"
                                    style="float: right;">
                                    <p:graphicImage value="../template/images/file_delete.png"
                                        width="48" height="48"></p:graphicImage>
                                </p:commandLink>


                            </p:outputPanel>
                        </p:column>
                    </p:dataTable>
                </p:outputPanel>
            </h:form>

            <p:dialog widgetVar="popEditTypeUtilisateur" modal="true"
                header="EDIT">
                <p:ajax event="close"
                    update=":Type_Utilisateur_Form:Type_Utilisateur_List" />
                <p:outputPanel autoUpdate="true">
                    <h:form>
                        <p:panelGrid columns="2" layout="grid">

                            <h:outputLabel value="User Type designation :" />
                            <p:inputText id="designationTypeUtilisateur"
                                value="#{typeUtilisateurBean.typeUtilisateur.designationTypeUtilisateur}" />

                        </p:panelGrid>
                        <p:commandButton value="Save" action="#{typeUtilisateurBean.save}"
                            oncomplete="if (!args.validationFailed) PF('popEditTypeUtilisateur').hide();" />
                        <p:commandButton value="Cancel"
                            action="#{typeUtilisateurBean.init}"
                            oncomplete="PF('popEditTypeUtilisateur').hide();" />
                    </h:form>
                </p:outputPanel>
            </p:dialog>


            <p:dialog widgetVar="popAddTypeUtilisateur" modal="true" header="Add">
                <p:ajax event="close"
                    update=":Type_Utilisateur_Form:Type_Utilisateur_List" />
                <p:outputPanel autoUpdate="true">
                    <h:form>
                        <p:panelGrid columns="2" layout="grid">


                            <h:outputLabel value=" User
                            Type designation :" />
                            <p:inputText id="designationTypeUtilisateur"
                                value="#{typeUtilisateurBean.typeUtilisateur.designationTypeUtilisateur}" />

                        </p:panelGrid>
                        <p:commandButton value="Save" action="#{typeUtilisateurBean.save}"
                            oncomplete="if (!args.validationFailed) PF('popAddTypeUtilisateur').hide();" />
                        <p:commandButton value="Cancel"
                            action="#{typeUtilisateurBean.init}"
                            oncomplete="PF('popAddTypeUtilisateur').hide();" />
                    </h:form>
                </p:outputPanel>
            </p:dialog>
        </ui:insert>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Comment: Kindly post full code with backing.

Comment: ok and thank you for replying.

Comment: What about some easy stuff by Primefaces itself

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/filter.xhtml
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/edit.xhtml

Comment: i used primefaces filter from http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/filter.xhtml and it work. In the other side row edit work fine.But the problem is when i search fields using filer then i try to update row i got a wrong row selection

Comment: I think its because you have not saved filtered data like in example: `filteredValue="#{dtFilterView.filteredCars}"`

Comment: i added it but i have the same problem.Even when i use primefaces row sorte i got a wrong row selection;always i got the last row selection !

Answer (score 0):

Here we go with primefaces example:
What is important:

- in this code set `editable="true"`
- `p:ajax event="rowEdit"` and `p:ajax event="rowEditCancel"` both listeners
- `f:facet name="output"` and `f:facet name="input"` for display, and
- edit a column with `p:rowEditor`

CODE .xhtml:

```
<p:dataTable id="cars1" var="car" value="#{dtEditView.cars1}" editable="true" style="margin-bottom:20px">
       <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{dtEditView.onRowEdit}" update=":form:msgs" />
       <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" listener="#{dtEditView.onRowCancel}" update=":form:msgs" />

       <p:column headerText="Id">
           <p:cellEditor>
               <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{car.id}" /></f:facet>
               <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText id="modelInput" value="#{car.id}" style="width:100%"/></f:facet>
           </p:cellEditor>
       </p:column>

       <p:column headerText="Year">
           <p:cellEditor>
               <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{car.year}" /></f:facet>
               <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText value="#{car.year}" style="width:100%" label="Year"/></f:facet>
           </p:cellEditor>
       </p:column>

       <p:column headerText="Brand">
           <p:cellEditor>
               <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{car.brand}" /></f:facet>
               <f:facet name="input">
                   <h:selectOneMenu value="#{car.brand}" style="width:100%">
                       <f:selectItems value="#{dtEditView.brands}" var="man" itemLabel="#{man}" itemValue="#{man}" />
                   </h:selectOneMenu>
               </f:facet>
           </p:cellEditor>
       </p:column>

       <p:column headerText="Color">
           <p:cellEditor>
               <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{car.color}" /></f:facet>
               <f:facet name="input">
                   <h:selectOneMenu value="#{car.color}" style="width:100%">
                       <f:selectItems value="#{dtEditView.colors}" var="color" itemLabel="#{color}" itemValue="#{color}" />
                   </h:selectOneMenu>
               </f:facet>
           </p:cellEditor>
       </p:column>

       <p:column style="width:32px">
           <p:rowEditor />
       </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Comment: If the problem still resist post your backing.

Answer (score 0):

in my table i have column named actions that contains two icons one for  update row and the other for delete row.I like to work like that.I have also iput text in order to filter my table and it's work.but if the function PF('carsTable').filter() is called i cannot get the right row selected !

IistUsers.xhtml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    template="../template/template.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="container clearfix">

        <ui:insert>

            <h:form id="Type_Utilisateur_Form">

                <p:commandLink action="#{typeUtilisateurBean.create()}"
                    oncomplete="PF('popAddTypeUtilisateur').show();"
                    style="font-size: 15px;">
                        Add user type                       
                    </p:commandLink>

                <p:outputPanel id="Type_Utilisateur_List" rendered="true">

                    <p:dataTable var="typeUtilisateur"
                        value="#{typeUtilisateurBean.listTypeUtilisateur}"
                        widgetVar="Type_Utilisateur_Table" rows="3" paginator="true"
                        rendered="true" emptyMessage="No records found with given criteria"
                        filteredValue="#{typeUtilisateurBean.filteredTypeUtilisateur}"
                        id="Type_Utilisateur_Table"
                        >

                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <p:outputPanel autoUpdate="true">
                                <p:inputText id="globalFilter"
                                    onkeyup="PF('Type_Utilisateur_Table').filter()"
                                    style="width:150px" placeholder="Search fields" />
                            </p:outputPanel>
                        </f:facet>

                        <p:column headerText="User Type designation"
                            sortBy="#{typeUtilisateur.designationTypeUtilisateur}"
                            filterBy="#{typeUtilisateur.designationTypeUtilisateur}"
                            filterStyle="display:none" filterMatchMode="contains">
                            <h:outputText
                                value="#{typeUtilisateur.designationTypeUtilisateur}" />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="Actions" style="width:120px">
                            <p:outputPanel>

                                <p:commandLink action="#{typeUtilisateurBean.getRow()}"
                                    oncomplete="PF('popEditTypeUtilisateur').show();" 

                                    >
                                    <p:graphicImage value="../template/images/file_edit.png"
                                        width="48" height="48"></p:graphicImage>
                                </p:commandLink>

                                <p:commandLink action="#{typeUtilisateurBean.delete}"
                                    update=":Type_Utilisateur_Form:Type_Utilisateur_List"
                                    style="float: right;">
                                    <p:graphicImage value="../template/images/file_delete.png"
                                        width="48" height="48"></p:graphicImage>
                                </p:commandLink>


                            </p:outputPanel>
                        </p:column>
                    </p:dataTable>
                </p:outputPanel>
            </h:form>

            <p:dialog widgetVar="popEditTypeUtilisateur" modal="true"
                header="EDIT">
                <p:ajax event="close"
                    update=":Type_Utilisateur_Form:Type_Utilisateur_List" />
                <p:outputPanel autoUpdate="true">
                    <h:form>
                        <p:panelGrid columns="2" layout="grid">

                            <h:outputLabel value="User Type designation :" />
                            <p:inputText id="designationTypeUtilisateur"
                                value="#{typeUtilisateurBean.typeUtilisateur.designationTypeUtilisateur}" />

                        </p:panelGrid>
                        <p:commandButton value="Save" action="#{typeUtilisateurBean.save}"
                            oncomplete="if (!args.validationFailed) PF('popEditTypeUtilisateur').hide();" />
                        <p:commandButton value="Cancel"
                            action="#{typeUtilisateurBean.init}"
                            oncomplete="PF('popEditTypeUtilisateur').hide();" />
                    </h:form>
                </p:outputPanel>
            </p:dialog>


            <p:dialog widgetVar="popAddTypeUtilisateur" modal="true" header="Add">
                <p:ajax event="close"
                    update=":Type_Utilisateur_Form:Type_Utilisateur_List" />
                <p:outputPanel autoUpdate="true">
                    <h:form>
                        <p:panelGrid columns="2" layout="grid">


                            <h:outputLabel value=" User
                            Type designation :" />
                            <p:inputText id="designationTypeUtilisateur"
                                value="#{typeUtilisateurBean.typeUtilisateur.designationTypeUtilisateur}" />

                        </p:panelGrid>
                        <p:commandButton value="Save" action="#{typeUtilisateurBean.save}"
                            oncomplete="if (!args.validationFailed) PF('popAddTypeUtilisateur').hide();" />
                        <p:commandButton value="Cancel"
                            action="#{typeUtilisateurBean.init}"
                            oncomplete="PF('popAddTypeUtilisateur').hide();" />
                    </h:form>
                </p:outputPanel>
            </p:dialog>
        </ui:insert>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

TypeUtilisateurBean:

```
package tn.com.bj.presentation;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.model.ListDataModel;

import org.primefaces.context.RequestContext;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

import tn.com.bj.entities.TypeUtilisateur;
import tn.com.bj.service.ITypeUtilisateurService;

@Controller("typeUtilisateurBean")
@Scope("session")
@ViewScoped
public class TypeUtilisateurBean implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("typeutilisateurService")
    private ITypeUtilisateurService typeUtilisateurService;

    private TypeUtilisateur typeUtilisateur = new TypeUtilisateur();
    private ListDataModel listTypeUtilisateur;
    private List<TypeUtilisateur> filteredTypeUtilisateur;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        listTypeUtilisateur = new ListDataModel();
        listTypeUtilisateur.setWrappedData(typeUtilisateurService
                .findAll(TypeUtilisateur.class));

    }

    public void create() {
        typeUtilisateur = new TypeUtilisateur();
    }

    public void getRow() {
        typeUtilisateur = (TypeUtilisateur) listTypeUtilisateur.getRowData();
    }

    public void delete() {
        getRow();
        typeUtilisateurService.deleteService(typeUtilisateur);
        listTypeUtilisateur.setWrappedData(typeUtilisateurService
                .findAll(TypeUtilisateur.class));
    }

    public void save() {
        typeUtilisateur = typeUtilisateurService
                .saveOrUpdateService(typeUtilisateur);
        init();
    }

    public ITypeUtilisateurService getTypeUtilisateurService() {
        return typeUtilisateurService;
    }

    public void setTypeUtilisateurService(
            ITypeUtilisateurService typeUtilisateurService) {
        this.typeUtilisateurService = typeUtilisateurService;
    }

    public TypeUtilisateur getTypeUtilisateur() {
        return typeUtilisateur;
    }

    public void setTypeUtilisateur(TypeUtilisateur typeUtilisateur) {
        this.typeUtilisateur = typeUtilisateur;
    }

    public ListDataModel getListTypeUtilisateur() {
        return listTypeUtilisateur;
    }

    public void setListTypeUtilisateur(ListDataModel listTypeUtilisateur) {
        this.listTypeUtilisateur = listTypeUtilisateur;
    }

    public List<TypeUtilisateur> getFilteredTypeUtilisateur() {
        return filteredTypeUtilisateur;
    }

    public void setFilteredTypeUtilisateur(
            List<TypeUtilisateur> filteredTypeUtilisateur) {
        this.filteredTypeUtilisateur = filteredTypeUtilisateur;
    }

}
```